# Give custom class names to WP nav sub-menu

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu

I'm creating a menu that will have sub-menu > sub-menu > sub-menu. The styling is really involved so ideally I could rename the class name "sub-menu" based off what level of sub-menu it is or at least add a class (ie 1st sub-menu add .top-sub-menu, 2nd sub-menu add .second-level-sub-menu, 3rd sub-menu add .third-level-sub-menu).

1. Is there any way to do this in WP core?
2. If not, are what would be the best way to achieve this result?

I attached the html of what I've got going on if that helps. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: have you tried any of these solutions? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name)

Comment: @Mari Hi, yes, this allows me to add a class to all instances of sub-menu but not to add different class names to nested sub-menu.

Comment: the first answer in the question Mari linked to contains the `$depth` of the menu items which is exactly what you're asking about, anybody with basic beginner level PHP skills can use an `if` statement to check its value and return a different class. The answer by vralle even uses the depth to add a class with the depth value and does it in a filter that can be added to any menu. Note that any answer you got here would not be a copy paste solution

Comment: @Mari I was actually able to use Artemiy Egorov's answer on that post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out by using a hook that I grabbed from Artemiy Egorov's answer on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034826/wp-nav-menu-change-sub-menu-class-name so I figured I'd share in case someone else needs it too:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'rename_sub_menus', 10, 3 );
function rename_sub_menus( $classes, $args, $depth ){
    foreach ( $classes as $key => $class ) {
    if ( $class == 'sub-menu'  && $depth == 0) {
        $classes[ $key ] = 'first-level-sub-menu';
    } else if ( $class == 'sub-menu'  && $depth == 1) {
      $classes[ $key ] = 'second-level-sub-menu';
    } else if ( $class == 'sub-menu'  && $depth == 2) {
      $classes[ $key ] = 'third-level-sub-menu';
    }
}

return $classes;
}
```